# Does DataService<T> Support Upsert (Insert or Replace)

Tags: wcf-data-services

As I understand it, the usual way for an OData-based service to support 'upsert' (i.e., insert a row, or update it if a row with this key already exists) is through a PUT request that includes a filter for the row and partition keys.

```
http://myaccount.table.core.windows.net/mytable(PartitionKey='myPartitionKey', RowKey='myRowKey1')
```

As far as I know, this is how Azure table storage supports upsert. But as far as I can tell, if you try the same thing on your own OData service implemented with the .NET Framework's built-in `DataService<T>`, this will only succeed if the row already exists. If the row does not exist, I'm getting a 404 error.

In other words, this is only working for updates, not inserts.

I suspect that upsert is simply not supported, but haven't been able to find a definitive answer. Can anyone tell me either how to do this, or confirm that I definitely can't?

Comment: Do a GET to determine if the row exists, and include or exclude the row/partition keys in your PUT, based on the result?

Comment: I know how to implement upsert in the absence of intrinsic support, thanks... (Your suggestion is incomplete by the way - there's a race condition in which some other client may have done the insert between your GET and PUT, so you also need to be prepared for failure and be ready to fall back to an update.) What I wanted to know was whether there's a way to support upsert. (I want it because I'm using `DataService<T>` to provide a faked up version of  Azure table storage for integration testing purposes. Azure supports upsert, so I want my fake to support it too.)

Comment: That's what I was already doing, but the problem with the home-brew-upsert is that it turns what could be a single request into at least two, and possibly three plus an exception. Not exactly efficient. (And this is motivated by a scenario in which load on table storage servers has become an issue.) That's why I asked the question you see above, and not "How can I do upsert with a service that doesn't support it?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try and create your own custom query provider (an implementation of IDataServiceQueryProvider).  If the user is requesting a single object that doesn't exist and the current http request's method is PUT, return a new one with the given id.  I *think* the built in update provider should be able to handle it from there and update the record.  Otherwise you might need your own update provider as well.

Using [WCF Data Services Toolkit](http://wcfdstoolkit.codeplex.com/) might make your job easier.  Otherwise you'll have to write your own linq provider which sounds like overkill for integration testing.

[This](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2010/01/07/data-service-providers-getting-started.aspx) is good series of blog posts on msdn describing how to build a custom ds provider.

Comment: Section 7 of that covers updates, and as far as I can tell, whether or not you provide a custom query implementation (as opposed to using the built-in reflection-based provider) seems not to alter the update semantics. It's `IDataServiceUpdateProvider` and `IUpdatable` either way, which I'm already using. (And it won't tell you that PUT is in use.) However, it's made me realise that I may have misunderstood `IUpdatable.GetResource` - returning a faked up item in that might work. I thought that could mess up queries, but of course those don't use `IUpdatable`. I'll try this and see...

Comment: I've marked this as an answer, because it pointed me in a directly that enabled me to solve this. However, the solution ended up looking quite difference in practice. The reasons for this are too complex to fit in a comment, so see the separate answer that I've posted.

Answer (score 2):

OK, I've tried what Jason Freitas suggested, and the results are too complex to address in a comment, so I'm adding an answer.

tl;dr: you can sort of do it, although the solution revolves around `IDataServiceUpdateProvider` and `IUpdatable`. (Jason suggested `IDataServiceQueryProvider`, which doesn't seem to help.) The problem, though, is that `DataService<T>` is not really designed to support upsert, and nor are the interfaces it uses for updates, so although you can get it working, the solution is a hack (and not in a good way), and one I suspect might cause problems in the future.

Long version:

I was already implementing `IUpdatable`, which is what's required to support updates, inserts, and deletes. `IDataServiceQueryProvider` doesn't add anything relating to update support, so `IUpdatable` is the key. I had originally made the mistake of thinking that arranging for `IUpdatable.GetResource` to return an item even if the requested item didn't exist would mess up the query behaviour. But of course, queries against `DataService<T>` don't go through `IUpdatable`, so it's possible to have that method return an object no matter what it's asked for.

It's surprisingly complicated to do that, and it also turns out not to be sufficient. Here's the code:

```
public object GetResource(IQueryable query, string fullTypeName)
{
    var item = query.Cast<object>().SingleOrDefault();
    if (item == null && fullTypeName != null)
    {
        var ctor = Type.GetType(fullTypeName).GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes);
        if (ctor != null)
        {
            item = ctor.Invoke(null);
            PopulatePutStandin(query.Expression, item);
        }
    }

    return item;
}

private void PopulatePutStandin(Expression expression, object item)
{
    var call = expression as MethodCallExpression;
    if (call != null && call.Method.Name == "Where" && call.Method.DeclaringType == typeof(Queryable))
    {
        foreach (Expression arg in call.Arguments)
        {
            var ux = arg as UnaryExpression;
            if (ux != null)
            {
                var op = ux.Operand as LambdaExpression;
                if (op != null)
                {
                    var bx = op.Body as BinaryExpression;
                    if (bx != null && bx.Method.Name == "op_Equality")
                    {
                        var left = bx.Left as MemberExpression;
                        var right = bx.Right as ConstantExpression;
                        if (left != null && right != null)
                        {
                            var prop = left.Member as PropertyInfo;
                            if (prop != null)
                            {
                                prop.SetValue(item, right.Value);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                PopulatePutStandin(arg, item);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That `GetResource` method is part of the `IUpdatable` interface, and it's the one that `DataService<T>` uses to try to find an existing resource when it receives a PUT. As you can see, if the object does not yet exist, it just constructs a new instance. However, it's not enough just to leave the new object in its default state. The `PartitionKey` and `RowKey` have to match the values on the incoming PUT request. And you don't get told these values directly - they are embedded in the query.

So I wrote that `PopulatePutStandin` method to pull those values out of the query. It walks through the chain of call expressions that represent the query, looking for `Where` calls. (This doesn't handle any other LINQ operators, but for an update/insert, you shouldn't see anything more complicated.) For each `Where` clause testing to see if a particular property has a particular value, my code sets that property to that value on the new object. In practice, this will end up setting just the `PartitionKey` and `RowKey` because those are the only `Where` clauses present for an upsert, but it was easier to write code that doesn't look for any particular properties.

This is slightly flaky in that it assumes that each property will be dealt with through its own `Where` clause. In theory, there's nothing stopping `DataService<T>` from using one `Where` clause that contains a single expression testing for both `PartitionKey` and `RowKey`. So in theory it could use either:

```
src.Where(e => e.PartitionKey == "123").Where(e => e.RowKey == "456")
```

or

```
src.Where(e => e.PartitionKey == "123" && e.RowKey == "456")
```

Those should both have the same effect. It happens to use the former, and my code relies on that, but I've not found any documentation in which `DataService<T>` promises to provide queries in any particular form. So we're sensitive to changes in implementation details in `DataService<T>`. A more robust implementation would want to handle either form, although it feels like trouble - in theory there are any number of ways we could be asked. It's not clear that there's a completely general and safe way to cruft up a new object that matches any query we might receive here.

However, this is code that runs in a test, so we'll detect that sort of problem at development time, so I guess it's acceptable.

However, although this enables us to produce a suitable target for the PUT, it turns out not to be enough. We get a `DataServiceException` with the following error:

> Since entity type
>   'Mm.Web.Tests.Fakes.AzureTableStorage.FakeUserPermission' has one or
>   more etag properties, If-Match HTTP header must be specified for
>   DELETE/PUT operations on this type.

The innards of `DataService<T>` have decided that a PUT request must include an ETag if it's to make any sense, because how else will you be sure you're editing the entity you meant to edit? That would make sense for an update, but obviously makes no sense for an insert. So this is not upsert-friendly.

I tried including an etag on the client side:

```
var permission = new TableEntity(userId, claimId) { ETag = "*" };
await _myTable.ExecuteAsync(TableOperation.InsertOrReplace(permission));
```

However, the Azure Table Storage client is apparently smart enough to know that etags make no sense for upsert. (If you know the etag, you know this is definitely an update, so you shouldn't be using upsert.) So it doesn't actually pass that ETag across.

However, you can work around this. Rather than just implementing `IUpdatable`, you can implement `IDataServiceUpdateProvider`, which derives from `IUpdatable`, and adds a single member:

```
public void SetConcurrencyValues(
    object resourceCookie,
    bool? checkForEquality,
    IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, object>> concurrencyValues)
{
}
```

If you implement this interface, you're basically telling `DataService<T>` that you want to handle ETags yourself. And since I'm perfectly happy for there to be no ETag, it's OK for this to do nothing. Simply providing an empty implementation of this interface disables the default ETag handling, and we no longer get the exception. So it sort of seems to work.

One problem is that there's no clear way to distinguish between a PUT or a DELETE at the point at which you're generating the fake stand-in. `GetResource` doesn't get told what the operation is. Or at least, not directly. As it happens, I've found that the `fullTypeName` argument happens to be `null` for a DELETE, but the documentation doesn't promise that. So I feel like I'm relying on an undocumented coincidence.

And that in turn feels like a symptom of an underlying problem: the interfaces involved here just aren't designed to support upsert. So although it's possible to get it to something resembling 'working', it's always going to be a somewhat unsatisfactory hack.

So I suspect the only satisfactory solution to this is to fake it at the HTTP level, because that's the only way to support the semantics I'm trying to fake.

Comment: Glad I could help.  What I was referring to in regards to IDataServiceQueryProvider was that the IQueryable passed into IUpdateProvider.GetResource is the return value of IDataServiceQueryProvider.GetQueryRootForResourceSet.   Your method is a lot easier since it doesn't require you to create a linq provider, but I wasn't sure if you'd get a 404 if you tried to PUT against something that didn't exist.  

In re distinguishing between PUT and DELETE could you use System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod ?

Comment: The way `DataService<T>` decides whether something exists is to call `GetResource`. So a "PUT against something that didn't exist" doesn't really happen, because we're just telling it that the resource exists (no matter what it asks for). Your HttpMethod suggestion will probably work, but right now, my code does not depend on an HttpContext, which makes it easier to test. (Yes, the code is *part* of a test, but it's complex enough that I feel it needs its own tests...) So I'm now wondering whether I might be able to infer the operation from subsequent `IUpdatable` calls.